# Change the scale of a plot in a graphic interface tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

I am trying to plot in a graphic interface and when I see what it looks like I want to change the scale with the button OK(def changerechelle is supposed to do that when I click OK) but it doesn't seem to work... I don't know why. I am a beginner so I don't understand everything I found on internet.

Here is the error I have:

> UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on
>   individual plots. warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "
>   Exception in Tkinter callback

And here is my code:

```
from numpy  import *from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from matplotlib.lines import *
from cmath import *
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
import os 
import imp
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk 
import pylab as pl

temps=linspace(0,50)
marche=linspace(0,50)

figure(1)

plot(temps, marche)

xlabel('Temps [heure]')
ylabel('Marche [s/j]')

grid(True)
legend(loc=0)


xmini=tk.DoubleVar()
ymini=tk.DoubleVar()
xmaxi=tk.DoubleVar()
ymaxi=tk.DoubleVar()

fenetre = tk.Tk() 

graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure(1), master=fenetre)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)


xmini= tk.Entry(fenetre, width=4)
xmini.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

label_xmin = tk.Label(fenetre, text = "Coord de l'abscisse minimale")
label_xmin.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

ymini = tk.Entry(fenetre, width=4)
ymini.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

label_ymin = tk.Label(fenetre, text = "Coord de l'ordonnée minimale")
label_ymin.grid(row = 2, column = 1) 

xmaxi = tk.Entry(fenetre, width=4)
xmaxi.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

label_xmax = tk.Label(fenetre, text = "Coord de l'abscisse maximale")
label_xmax.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

ymaxi = tk.Entry(fenetre, width=4)
ymaxi.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

label_ymax = tk.Label(fenetre, text = "Coord de l'ordonnée maximale")
label_ymax.grid(row = 4, column = 1) 

def changerechelle() : 
    xmin = xmini.get()
    xmax = xmaxi.get()
    ymin = ymini.get()
    ymax = ymaxi.get()

    figure(1)

    plot(temps, marche)
    xlim(xmin,xmax)
    ylim(ymin,ymax)

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure(1), master=fenetre)
    canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

bouton=tk.Button(fenetre, text="OK", command=changerechelle)
bouton.grid(row=2,column=3)

close(figure(1))

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you've summed up the problem, "I am a beginner so I don't understand everything I found on internet.". So don't find code on the internet, start with a novice tutorial and build the code from scratch.

Comment: yeah this is what I've done but now I 've got a problem I can't fix... I meant that when I look to solve my problem I don't understand what I found.

Comment: I cannot run your script, `linspace()` is not defined, is this from a module you have failed to include?

Comment: It works for me, I edit my post to add what I have imported for my script.